# Swear on versus swear to the Bible

Tags: prepositions

I was wondering whether both prepositions "on" and "to" work in the following examples in the same semantic manner. If they would change the meaning of each sentence, then how?

> - In some countries, witnesses in court have to swear **on** Bible.
> - In some countries, witnesses in court have to swear **to** Bible.

IMO based on Google search the both prepositions should work here.

Comment: I think you meant to ask for "to the Bible" vs. "on the Bible" in the body of the post.

Comment: (Some) Christians swear ON the Bible in a court of law because they place a hand on the book while taking the oath. The custom of oath taking various widely in different cultures. There's a detailed history of the practice, dating back several thousand years, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath

Comment: You've drawn the wrong conclusion from your Google searches, 1) there is no such construction as **on** + bare infinitive and 2) when "have" means "must" it is followed by the marked infinitive: "have **to**"+ infinitive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the body of the question does not reflect the question posed in the title. The question needs to be edited to make sense in that regard.

Comment: You need to edit the question. You have written: "... **to** *swear on the Bible*" and ".... **on** *swear on the Bible*" The title in your question is quite different, but the fix is simple.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mari-LouA and Max. You were right. It way a typo and I beg your pardon.

Answer (score 1):

The two phrases have slightly different meaning.

If you swear **on** something, you place your hand on it and recite the words of an oath.  The placing of the hand on the bible indicates that you are making your oath before God and it is therefore binding.

When I performed Jury Service I was asked to swear *on* the bible.  I refused as I am not Christian.  Therefore, I was asked to swear *to* judge the case - to "affirm".

If you swear **to** something there is no holy book present.  You make your oath on your own authority.

Thus, both prepositions can be used in the same sentence:
*You swear on the Bible to tell the truth.*
Both prepositions relate to the swearing